# IBM MobileFirst application in SIT and UAT test environments

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Please let me know, to deploy Mobilefirst application in SIT and UAT test environments do we need to go with Enterprise edition or is there any other way we can use developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the developer edition anywhere else other than in Eclipse, not only because the license is different and you... must pay..., but also technically - the developer edition is missing key components, such as the Server component. Without this, you cannot create any test or sit or prod environments.